# D2010 Beta: The Perfect Way to support Multi-Core

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing, delphi-2010, multicore

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665143/delphi-2010-beta-whats-on-your-wishlist) about the expected features in the new D2010 one of the highest rated answers was 'Multi-Core Support'.

Well, as we all know Delphi support thread programming since D2 (IIRC) and is used heavily in some areas. More specifically which is, in your opinion, the perfect way to support parallel programming in Delphi? (But not only - let's not tie the question entirely to Delphi).

Personally I tend to see that a combined approach will do, depending on situation: threads (anyway we have them), the actor model and the task-based approach (which is in fact near to the actor model).

Also, IMHO, it would very interesting to investigate a visual modeling tool to describe the interaction between actors.

Also a visual debugger (which perhaps is the same tool with the one above) would be very welcomed.

Some references:

- [General discussion about multi-core programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121674/multi-core-and-concurrency-languages-libraries-and-development-techniques)
- [Discussion about parallel programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79999/what-parallel-programming-model-do-you-recommend-today-to-take-advantage-of-the)
- [Allen Bauer on Delphi Parallel Library](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/category/parallel-programming)

Your opinion which would be?

Comment: If you make these discussion questions wiki, you will be less likely to be downvoted and closed, since you cannot be accused of rep-whoring.

Comment: Although I haven't downvoted you or voted for closing on this one, myself :)

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is the right venue for a discussion like this. Go ask on Embarcadero's newsgroup, where people can write longer responses to others' ideas, instead of being limited to 300 characters and an "up" or "down" vote.

Answer (score 4):

Make it compatible with the Async calls in Delphi Prism, at least syntactically.

Comment: Delphi Prism is .NET IDE. It is very different from regular Delphi